# Beginner python ( Tkinter ) - How to ask for a rate to make a currency conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am a beginner in programming so I'm sorry if the code is confusing or too long.
My question is: I am stuck with the rate input and how to put everything together to make the conversion works?

Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

def convertDtoE():

    fromDtoE=fromDtoEVar
    fromDtoEVar.get()
    fromEtoD=fromEtoDVar
    fromEtoDVar.get()

    fromDtoEVar.set(fromEtoD)
def convertEtoD():

    fromDtoE=fromDtoEVar
    fromDtoEVar.get()
    fromEtoD=fromEtoDVar
    fromEtoDVar.get()

    fromEtoDVar.set(fromDtoE)
def main():
    window=Tk()

    global fromDtoEVar
    fromDtoEVar=DoubleVar()

    fromDtoEVar.set(0.0)

    global fromEtoDVar
    fromEtoDVar=DoubleVar()

    fromEtoDVar.set(0.0)

    aa=Label(window,text="Dollars")
    aa.pack()
    a=Entry(window,textvariable=fromDtoEVar)
    a.pack()
    rr=Label(window,text="Rate")
    rr.pack()
    rate=Entry(window)
    rate.pack()
    bb=Label(window,text="Euros")
    bb.pack()
    b=Entry(window,textvariable=fromEtoDVar)
    b.pack()
    c=Button(window, text="Convert Euros", command=convertEtoD)
    c.pack()
    d=Button(window, text="Convert Dollars", command=convertDtoE)
    d.pack()
    window.mainloop()
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix your line indents

Comment: Also please fix the apparently randomized newlines, and the stray characters like the `*` on the first `fromDtoEVar.set` line.

Comment: And as a side note, it really helps to give your variables meaningful names instead of `a` and `aa`. (Or, if you don't have any reason to keep them around, don't give them names at all—just `Entry(window, textvariable=fromDtoEVar).pack()`.)

Comment: I've just edited the code. Sorry i'm just a beginner, what I am trying to understand is: How to put inside the code the equation to calculate and convert the currencies using a rate (input from the user)

Comment: @Alfiebrown: You have to fetch the rate value the same way you fetch the other two values, and then you can write the code to do the conversion (`fromDtoE = fromEtoD / rate`… or is that `* rate`? I'm not sure which way your app is meant to go…), right before your `set` call (`fromDtoEVar.set(fromDtoE)`), so it ends up using the computed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but there's one very big problem with your code that you repeat multiple times, so I'll assume that's what you want fixed:

```
fromDtoE=fromDtoEVar
fromDtoEVar.get()
```

This does nothing useful. It returns the current value of the `DoubleVar`, which you then ignore. Meanwhile, you've bound another name to the `DoubleVar` itself, but then you use the original name. I think what you wanted is:

```
fromDtoE=fromDtoEVar.get()
```

Now, at least, you'll be copying actually numbers around, instead of the string representations of Tk variables like `PY_VAR0`.

You're still not actually doing any conversions, just copying the numbers back and forth. To fix that, first you're going to need to actually access the value in the Rate widget. You can attack a `DoubleVar` to that the same way you do the other two widgets, access its value in the same way, and then just do the math.